# program runs in safe mode but not in normal mode for Win7 in a virtual box

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, compatibility, safe-mode

I recently installed a program on Win7 (hosted on a virtual box that runs on a Linux machine). The program runs correctly in Windows safe mode (no network) but fails to start in normal mode (0xc0000142 error). The same program works fine on other machines on Win7. I've tried to make a clean boot with msconfig with only system services checked but the program still fails to launch.
What should I try next?

Edit:
I resorted to trial and error and solved the problem by uninstalling several old and unnecessary programs that were not, as far as I know, related to the new one.

For my understanding, does anyone know how uninstalling programs that had not been run in months might have resolved the issue?

Comment: A `0xc0000142` error normally indicates a DLL problem.

Comment: open the tool in depends.exe (dependy walker), press F7 for tracing and look for details in the tracing log.

Comment: I didn't have time to look into dependency walker but uninstalling a bunch of old programs I had no use for did the trick. I have no idea which one was causing the issue and will probably never know. I removed several at once and none of them were directly related to the new program. I'm not satisfied with having to use trial and error to solve issues like this though.

Comment: @user619412 - In the future be sure you are willing to attempt several different things, telling us you do not or didn't have the time to do something, isn't the type of attitude that allows us to help you. The funny thing is the dependency walker suggestion, wouldn't have been "trial and error", it would have told you exactly what was missing.

Comment: @Ramhound what I mean't was the issue was resolved in the aforementioned way before I saw the comment on depends.exe. Hence the lack of satisfaction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been resolved by deleting an unknown list of unused old programs, so unlikely to be of use to any future readers.